# Как сделать print вместо System.out.print?

Tags: java

Как укоротить запись `System.out.println()` или где взять уже готовый пакет?

Comment: Вы хотите укоротить запись? Или вам нужен какой-то другой print?

Comment: Укоротить запись. Желательно для всех методов в System.out

Comment: public class Logger
{
   private final static String NULL = "null";

   public static void main ( final String [] args )
   {
      new Logger ().log ( "Hello World", "!!!" );
      new Logger ().log ( "current time is = ", new Date () );
   }

   public void log ( final Object... ф )
   {
      if ( null == ф )
      {
         System.out.println ( NULL );
         return;
      }

      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ();
      for ( Object o : ф )
      {
         s.append ( ( null == o ? NULL : o ) );
      }

      System.out.println ( s );
   }
}

Comment: public class Logger
    {
     private final static String NULL = "null";
     public static void main ( final String [] args )
     {
       new Logger ().log ( "Hello World", "!!!" );
       new Logger ().log ( "current time is = ", new Date () );
     }
     public void log ( final Object... ф )
     {
       if ( null == ф )
       {
         System.out.println ( NULL );
         return;
       }
       StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ();
       for ( Object o : ф )
       {
         s.append ( ( null == o ? NULL : o ) );
       }
       System.out.println ( s );
     }
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sout + [tab]

Но если так уж сильно сильно хочется, то можно сделать класс со статическими методами типа такого (правда, придётся руками все нужные перечислять)

```
public class SystemOutPrint {
    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Тогда можно будет применить static import

```
import static SystemOutPrint.print;

public class Main {
    public void test() {
        print("zzz");
    }
}
```

Тем не менее, всё ещё не понятно, зачем такое понадобилось. Если надо много клеить, то можно использовать StringBuilder

```
System.out.print( new StringBuilder()
        .append("zzz")
        .append(777));
```

Или, возможно, даже просто плюсом склеивать (StringBuilder будет создан неявно).

Comment: Огромное спасибо !  Это то, что надо. 

Я начал осваивать Java, поэтому много тестовой печати на консоль для посмотреть что получается, поэтому набивать длинные правильные слова напрягает.

Comment: добавлю, что в Eclipse аналогичный shortcut по умолчанию: "sysout" Ctrl + Space.

Comment: Попробовал в разных вариантах, оказалось лучше в **print(String s)** вместо **String** писать **Object**

Comment: Это может оказаться менее эффективным, чем указывать конкретные типы. И может подвести вас при работе с массивами. Впрочем, стандартный println ведёт себя так же. С другой стороны, если вам это для теста надо, то наплевать.