# Статический импорт println()

Tags: java, импорт, static

Не понимаю, почему не работает такой импорт:

```
import static java.lang.System
```

Возникает ошибка.

Я хотел сделать импорт `println` удобным, чтобы не писать `System.out`...

Comment: `import static java.lang.System.out;` работает, потом вызываете `out.println();`. Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2504115/4752653. Просто до `println()` не получится сократить, т.к. out - это уже не пакет или класс, а объект класса PrintStream, от которого уже вызывается метод println.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод в Java println без `System.out`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326510); [Как сделать print вместо `System.out.print`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18422/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический импорт работает для доступа к **статическим** полям / методам, поэтому следует записать `import static java.lang.System.*;`, чтобы "сократить" написание `System`: `out.println()`.

Методы `print / println` в классе `PrintStream` НЕ являются статическими, поэтому к ним статический импорт не применим.

Чтобы дополнительно сократить `out.println`, можно реализовать свой класс со статическими методами с краткими названиями, в которых будут вызываться соответствующие методы для `System.out`:

```java
package my.util;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Out {
    public static p(Object obj) {
        out.println(obj);
    }

    public static f(String format, Object ... args) {
        out.printf(format, args);
    }
// ... и т.д.
}
```

Тогда можно импортировать статические методы уже из своего утилитарного класса:

```java
import static my.util.Out.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.toString;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        p("Hello World");                  // Out.p -> System.out.println
        f("My args %s%n", toString(args)); // Out.f -> System.out.printf
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Создайте новый класс к примеру Helper с функциями которые должны упростить ввод

```
public class Helper {
    public static void println(Object line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

в классе в котором вы хотите использовать println

**import static package_example.Helper.println;**

после этого вы можете использовать пример

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем ещё один класс? Чем плох статический импорт поля out из класса System? К тому же в ваш пример ещё нужно перегрузки добавлять для вывода примитивов.